# undefined reference to `geten_'

Tags: compiler-errors, undefined-reference

I am new to ubuntu. i am trying to compile a program given at http://www-tcad.stanford.edu/tcad/programs/oldftpable.html But it is giving errors: Undefined reference

What am I missing?

```
   subroutine opnfl(lu,cname,opnerr,ierr,status,form,exclus,appnd)
      logical opnerr,form,exclus,appnd
      integer lu,ierr,status
      character*(*) cname
      logical vaxdev
      logical geten
      character*80 fname
      character*12 aform
      character*8 astat
      character*13 aexcl
      character*3 old
      character*3 new
      character*7 unknow
      character*7 scrat
      character*9 formtd
      character*11 unform
      character*9 exclsv
      character*12 nonexc
      data old / 'old' / 
      data new / 'new' / 
      data unknow / 'unknown' / 
      data scrat / 'scratch' / 
      data formtd / 'formatted' / 
      data unform / 'unformatted' / 
      data exclsv / 'exclusive' / 
      data nonexc / 'nonexclusive' / 
      opnerr=.false.
      ierr=0
      call csetv(fname, 80, ' ')
      if(.not.(.not.geten(cname,fname)))goto 23000
      call cpack(cname,fname, len(cname))
23000 continue
      if(.not.(status .eq. 1))goto 23002
11    continue
      opnerr=.true.
      return
      end
```

I have attached the error below.

```
:~/Downloads/Release/src/setup$ make install
loading...
opnfl-L.o: In function `opnfl_':
opnfl-L.f:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `geten_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:39: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The PISCES code is quite old.  Apart from fixing the build system, and the linker errors, you may encounter issues with syntax errors in the code that would not work on a modern Linux system.

If you wish to compile PISCES with a newer build system, please see the fork I created here:
https://github.com/devsim/pisces

Note that it has been only tested with a couple of test cases.  If you have trouble with the application, please file a ticket.